# What is correct form Wonder or Wondering

Tags: grammar

You make me wonder/wondering what you are speaking about this

Comment: Either I did wonder, wondered or was wondering.

Comment: Ing - adjective is source of feeling. I don't clear it

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: ***“You make me”*** is followed by infinitive without to: https://www.perfect-english-grammar.com/let-and-make.html - You make me wonder …. See also: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=make+me+wonder%2C+make+me+wondering&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmake%20me%20wonder%3B%2Cc0

Comment: this is Helpful link, thank you

Comment: Note also….  *”what you are speaking about*” or “*why you are speaking about this.*”

Answer (score 1):

Further to user 66974's answer, there are rules governing when it is appropriate to use the gerund (wondering).  Briefly, they are:

1. Gerunds are used only after certain verbs, including enjoy, like/dislike, fancy, discuss, finish, mind, suggest, recommend, keep, and avoid.

- *I dislike swimming in deep water.*

2. They are also used after prepositions of place and time:

- *I stopped for pizza before getting home.*
- *I felt better after eating something.*

3. To replace the subject or object of a sentence

- *Marcin likes eating pizza.*
- *Jumping off a cliff into deep water is dangerous, but a real thrill.*